# after configuring my .htaccess file bootstrap css is not working?

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, .htaccess

i am using below code in my .htaccess file to remove .php from my url, but the bootstrap css is not working.

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

site url: www.andamanexoticholidays.com/index

any kind of help would be appriciated.

Comment: Please add more detail. What exactly do you mean by the css not working?

Comment: You might want to show us your directory structure, the location of your css files and the way you include your css files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your redirect rules before internal rewrites and also check whether corresponding `.php` files exist before add `.php` internally.

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

For css/js etc make sure to add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />` so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.

Comment: thanks a lot. it worked for me but in my header file the current url is not getting .active class.

Comment: plz do have a look in andamanexoticholidays.com/packages.php and andamanexoticholidays.com/packages

Comment: Both `/packages/` and `/packages.php` look same in my browser. Clear your browser cache and retest.

Comment: see the menu bar, in packages.php packages tab is getting active and getting red background but in packages/ index.php still remains active with red bg

Comment: That has nothing to rewrite rules. Check your php/js code that does this highlighting.

Comment: ok. anyways thanks a lot for ur help. :D